# laravel 9 donwloading pdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, download

I have this element:

view:

```
<li><a href="{{route('front.download')}}" target="_blanck">Download PDF</a></li>
```

controller:

```
public function download(){
    $document = Documents::first();
    return response()->download(url('uploads/documents/'.$document->filename));

}
```

I'm having this issue:

```
The file "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/documents/1-1654548555.pdf" does not exist
```

I checked the directory uploads/documents and the file 1-1654548555.pdf exist, what is wrong?

Comment: Where is your "uploads" directory located? By default, only public/ directory and its content is opened for web server.

Comment: It's in public, let me added

Comment: by default "url()" added public, when I push "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/documents/1-1654548555.pdf" on chrome, It show file

Comment: response()->download() method accepts the path to the file, not url: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#file-downloads
So if you want to force file download, you can pass filepath instead of url.
Alternatively, you can setup rules to force download for upload folder on web server level (apache/nginx)

Comment: ahmmmm that part I did'n know.

Comment: this work fot me ```return response()->download(public_path("/uploads/documents/".$document->filename));```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
/**
 * download file
 * 
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response
 */

public function download(Request $request)
{
    $file = public_path(). "uploads/documents/";

    $headers = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];

    return \Response::download($file, 'test.pdf', $headers);
}
```